# Javascript click events firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is my function running multiple times?

```
var s,
getData = {

    settings: {
        gender: $("input[name='gender']"),
        age: $("input[name='age']")
    },

    init: function() {
        s = this.settings;
        this.getInput();
    },

    getInput: function() {
        for (i in s) {
            s[i].on("click", function() {
                s[i].off();
                console.log(this.getAttribute('value'))
            });
        }
    },
};
```

What I find odd is that when I don't click the same input twice it only runs once. For instance if I click 'male' and then 'female' it would show in the console

```
(1) male
(2) female
```

which logically makes sense to me, if I clicked 'male' 5 times then I get

```
(14) male
```

and it just gets larger and larger.

EDIT:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1gbzut6/) If you open console you can see what happens

Comment: why the complicated code ?

Comment: post you code ?

Comment: @madalinivascu why is it complicated? It's modular code, which is cleaner imo.

Comment: @passion I posted the code in a JSFiddle

Comment: @madalinivascu is right this is way too complicated. See my answer for the solution

Comment: @self i know see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that `getInput` is being called for each click event, meaning that the loop is running each time, registering the event again. So each time you click the radio button the loop will attach an event to the DOM element again. **You should only register the event once**: https://jsfiddle.net/2jbLdo9n/

Remove the `onclick` event on the input:

```
<div class="right-item">
  <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
  <label class="left-m" for="male"><span></span> Male </label>
</div>
<div class="right-item">
  <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female"><span></span> Female </label>
</div>
```

Then in your JavaScript, just call `getData.init();`

```
getData.init();
```

Comment: @DanielContreras see my answer.

Comment: oh I hadn't realized that onclick worked that way. I'll try it without onclick() in html. But how would the form dynamically retrieve any changes? My script isn't inline like the JSFiddle, I just did it that way because the getInput function wasn't working. However, the javascript wouldn't continuously listen would it?

Comment: @DanielContreras Each time the form is clicked, the values will be retrieved dynamically. And you'll have access to the value in the click handler, the one that is in your loop.

Comment: @DanielContreras `.on("click",function(){})` is the attribute `onclick` that you are asked to remove  so the on event continuously listens to find a click event

Comment: @madalinivascu  I think he is confusing angular style dynamic things with regular plain javascript events :)

Comment: oh! I got it! I used suggestions from all 3 of you and they got me to where I needed to be. The biggest issue was the onclick() that was occuring inside the html file. It does make sense that they're the same function, but for some reason it went over my head. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

bind a single click event, if you are calling this multiple time then first remove the click event and the append it once again or use `one()`

try the following:

```
var s,
getData = {

    settings: {
        gender: "input[name='gender']",
        age: "input[name='age']"
    },

    init: function() {
        s = this.settings;
        this.getInput();
    },

    getInput: function() {

            $(s.gender+','+s.age).on("click", function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
    },
};
```

remove the click event and initiate the call at document ready

see demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qzrfwc3g/

or do it the normal way 3 lines of code:

```
$("input[name='gender'],input[name='age']").on("click", function() {
     console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I tried the .one() function but it still has odd behavior. However, it did stop the multiple calls to my function.

Comment: what do you mean by odd?

Comment: wait you are creating a click event from a click event, why?

Comment: He should only register the event once, not multiple times like he's doing.

Comment: I suppose the reason I tried it with a loop is because I have multiple inputs and when I did it that way all I saw was repeated code. I guess what I really wanted to do was have a way that my document can listen to all inputs without writing out 100 lines of code. Maybe I'm wrong and can't do that though?

Comment: if all your inputs will have a name of gender or age they will trigger the click event,if the click event is not triggered for one of these inputs then that means you input is dynamically  added so you need to use event delegation

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want do it like this , as you code , I think there is a error here .

```
for (i in s) {
  s[i].on("click", function() {
      s[i].off();
      console.log(this.getAttribute('value'))
   });
}
```

You declare `i` as global , when event fires , `i` refers the same value .You can try this :

```
for (let i in s) {
      s[i].on("click", function() {
          s[i].off();
          console.log(this.getAttribute('value'))
       });
    }
```

Comment: You're right, the i variable was not being reset after every function call. I wasn't aware that my variable was a global variable. I'm fairly new to JS so I'm still trying to learn it. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding multiple click events to same element that why you get multiple console.log for one click. To resolve this just add a condition before assigning event listners.

```
var s,
    getData = {

      cacheDOM: {
        gender: $("input[name='gender']"),
        age: $("input[name='age']")
      },

      init: function() {
        if(!s){
            s = this.cacheDOM;
            this.getInput();
        }
      },

      getInput: function() {
        for (i in s) {
          s[i].on("click", function() {
            s[i].off();
            console.log(this.getAttribute('value'))
          });
        }
      },
    };
```