# Javascript "onkeyup" event is firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple code, expecting "Enter pressed" showing in the console every time the enter key is pressed when typing in an editable table cell (CELL2).

```js
console.log('working');

function enterKeyCheck(x) {
  x.addEventListener('keypress', function(y) {
    if (y.which == 13) {
      y.preventDefault();
      console.log('Enter Pressed')
    };
  });
};
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>CELL1</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="enterKeyCheck(this)">CELL2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  CHECKING
</div>
```

I was expecting The "enter pressed" message once for every enter key hit, but looks like I get multiple of them each time, and I think the message is logged as many times as the number of characters types before pressing the enter key.

1. Can someone explain why this is happening? I think I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652419/javascript-click-events-firing-multiple-times), but I am not able to comprehend why the whole loop would run multiple times even if the "which == 13" condition holds only once.
2. More importantly, how do I prevent this, using vanilla javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: on each `keyup` event you are adding a brand new event listener for `keypress`. None of these event listeners are ever being removed.

Answer (score 2):

You are attaching the event twice , once inline in html and other inside the `enterKeyCheck` function. Instead of `this` pass the `event` object from the event handler and in the function check the event code

```js
function enterKeyCheck(y) {
  if (y.which === 13) {
    y.preventDefault();
    console.log('Enter Pressed')
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>CELL1</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="enterKeyCheck(event)">CELL2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  CHECKING
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The only reason I did this because preventDefault does not work without eventListener. The above code mostly works, but I was avoiding the cursor going to second line after enter press, but the above code does not stop that. Also, do you mind telling a bit more about how this is called twice, if the first event is only a call to the second event?

Answer (score 0):

`onkeyup` is already firing `enterKeyCheck` for every keypress, and you have another event listener within your `enterKeyCheck` that's being called, therefore calling it twice. You should only need one of them.

Comment: So it is one function calling another calling execution, why is execution happening twice? Plus, it is not just twice, it logs the message 6 times, if I type 6 characters like "abcdef", before pressing enter. Function should be called only once, the way I see it.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the cell, the `onkeyup` is calling `enterKeyCheck` which again has a listener for keypress, that's being fired.
You could rewrite your function to something like this, to fix the issue.

```
document.querySelector('#cell').onkeyup = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
            console.log('Enter pressed') //do something
        }
    };
```

Add an id to the cell to be recognizable.

```
<div id="test1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>CELL1</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" id="cell">CELL2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  CHECKING
</div>
```

Comment: Prajwal, thank you, but I needed to use preventDefault, because otherwise the cursor goes to next line too when Enter key is pressed. That is the only reason I had to use eventlistener.

Comment: Did you try adding ```e.preventDefault()``` before the 'if' block ?

Answer (score 0):

there are some repeating things happening for using `this` at the `enterKeyCheck` method. Each time you click, it's firing the total clicks and consoling for the last one. To avoid that you just need to use `event` instead of `this`. In that case, the code would be like:

```
<td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="enterKeyCheck(event)">CELL2</td>
```

```
function enterKeyCheck(x) {
  if (x.which == 13) {
      x.preventDefault();
      console.log('Enter Pressed')
    };
};
```

If you use the above ways I think it will reach out to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Robin, however, I don't like that after the enter key is pressed, the cursor goes to next line, which is why I needed preventDefault, and that does not work without eventlistener. The preventDefault part in your suggestion does not work.